# Escribir doubles con fwrite en c

Tags: c, archivo

Voy a hacer una pregunta tal vez de novato. Estoy usando la función `fwrite` en **C** para escribir datos `double` en un archivo de texto, pero cuando abro el archivo no se leen los números sino una serie de símbolos y cuando utilizo archivos binarios para escritura o lectura no hay problema (pues no los abro en el editor de texto), pero si uso archivos de texto me da problemas al escribir datos `int` o `double`. Mi código de ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
  FILE *fp;


  unsigned int dinero[10] = { 23, 12, 45, 345, 512, 345, 654, 287, 
  567, 124 };

   fp = fopen ( "fichero.txt", "w" );


   fwrite( &dinero[0], sizeof(unsigned int), 10, fp );

   fclose ( fp );

   return 0;
  }
```

Todos los códigos de ejemplos de la web son así. En ningún lado encontré información de si esa función se usa solo con archivos binarios.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Bueno voy a contar un poco lo que veo. Solo por aportar algo.
Cuando abro el archivo con el editor gedit y escribí solo texto se lee bien el texto. Si escribí text y números ya sea int, float o double el texto se lee pero en lugar de numeros aparecen simbolos desordenados (aparentemente). 
Si lo abro con el editor sublime text y el archivo contiene texto y numeros lo que se ve es lo siguiente:

> ```
>    4d6f 7374 7261 6e64 6f20 656c 2075 736f
>    2064 6520 6677 7269 7465 2065 6e20 756e
>    2066 6963 6865 726f 2e0a 0100 0000
> ```

Por lo que averigue es el codigo ascii del texto mas el numero.
Si el archivo contiene solo texto se lee el texto normalmente.
Y si el archivo contiene solo numeros sublime text me muestra lo siguiente:

> 0100 0000

Ingrese un solo numero que es el 1. El tipo de dato ingresado es unsigned int.Le busco forma que sea uno binario o algo pero no. Si es double el archivo tiene otra cosa. 
Bueno realmente me fui por las ramas y mi intencion era aportar algo pero tal vez no sirva de nada.
Mi duda en si es porque no puedo ver los numeros escritos en un archivo de texto si uso la funcion fwrite. 
Bueno mi conclusion es que el texto puedo escribirlo en archivos txt pero los numeros debo escribirlos en archivos binarios. El 0100 0000 es 1 en hexadecimal. Los enteros ocupan 4 bytes y tengo dos digitos por byte. 
Puedo usar la funcion para escribir y al leerlo del archivo con fread lo guardo en un arreglo para trabajar con los numeros. El resto fue solo curiosidad de porque no puedo ver el archivo de texto correctamente cuando ingreso numeros.

Comment: cuando llame a la función de la biblioteca C, como `fopen()` y `fwrite()`, siempre verifique el valor devuelto para asegurar que la operación fue exitosa.

Comment: Deseas insertar todos los numeros o solo uno en particular??

Comment: Concretamente voy a insertar tal vez 100000 numeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Estoy usando la función fwrite en C para escribir datos double en un archivo de texto, pero cuando abro el archivo no se leen los números sino una serie de símbolos y cuando utilizo archivos binarios para escritura o lectura no hay problema

Es algo esperable. `fwrite` es una utilidad de escritura binaria, es decir, no trata de ninguna forma los datos a guardar.

Si tu usas `fwrite` con en tu ejemplo:

```
fwrite( &dinero[0], sizeof(unsigned int), 10, fp );
```

Lo que se va a guardar en el fichero es la representación binaria de `dinero[0]`, es decir, de 23. En el fichero se guardaría por tanto la siguiente secuencia hexadecimal:

```
0000 0000 0000 0017
```

Si intentas abrir este fichero en modo texto tendrás 7 caracteres nulos y un último caracter reservado cuyo significado sería *End of transaction block*. Es decir... nada legible.

Para recuperar la información guardada en binario tienes que recurrir a `fread` que lee los datos de forma binaria... así, al almacenar la secuencia anterior en la memoria asociada a una variable de tipo `unsigned int`, tu aplicación entenderá que en dicha variable se encuentra el númeor `23` original.

Para que los datos del fichero sean legibles por un *humano*  es necesario guardarlos en formato texto y esto implica darle cierto tratamiento a los datos... no puedes guardar su representación binaria sino que tienes que usar una que sea legible... una solución pasaría por convertir los números a texto y para eso puedes usar, como te ha comentado [@DarielRamosDiazVillegas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/156426/463), `fprintf`

Comment: Muchas gracias @eferion. Si bien es algo que venia sospechando que el uso de fwrirte es para ficheros binarios es bueno que alguien me lo confirme. En las web que visité ninguna decia que el uso de fwrite es exclusivo binario. De nuevo gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes emplear la función fprintf que es similar a printf solo que la salida la hace en el fichero que pasas como primer parámetro ejemplo:

```
FILE *fp;

unsigned int dinero[10] = { 23, 12, 45, 345, 512, 345, 654, 287, 
567, 124 };

char str[] = "This is tutorialspoint.com";

fp = fopen( "file.txt" , "w" );
int i = 0;
//Recorro el arreglo y voy añadiendo cada número si deseara solo imprimir 1 ejecuto el cuerpo del ciclo for
// solamente e indico el indice del arreglo que quiero imprimir en el archivo
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    fprintf(fp, (i != 9) ? "%d, ": "%d", dinero[i]);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Esa es la forma en la que lo hacia. Pero quise sacar el ciclo usando la funcion fwrite.